# "No context is current or a function that is not available in the current context was called" - LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMiggUPst-Q&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP&index=3&ab_channel=ThinMatrix) on LWJGL but since it's from 2014 and a lot has changed since then, I had to adapt my code when creating the display and context. Now I am getting the error:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: Thread[main,5,main]: No context is current or a function that is not available in the current context was called. The JVM will abort execution.
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30C.nglGenVertexArrays(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30C.glGenVertexArrays(GL30C.java:2420)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.glGenVertexArrays(GL30.java:2346)
    at engine.ModelLoader.createVAO(ModelLoader.java:41)
    at engine.ModelLoader.loadToVAO(ModelLoader.java:26)
    at engine.Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

... even though I made sure to glfwMakeContextCurrent() and GL.createCapabilities() before actually creating the VAO. The creation of the context is at DisplayManager:init(), which is being called on the second line in the main function, and Java is failing at ModelLoader:loadToVAO, which is called after that.

I am running on only one thread (the main one) and I don't think the context isn't being initialized because it's in a different class, that would be stupid.

Any help would be appreciated!

Main.java:

```java
package engine;

import graphics.DisplayManager;
import graphics.Renderer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

/**
 * @author Rafael Barbieru
 * Entry class of the engine.
 */
public class Main {

    // Attributes
    private static DisplayManager displayManager;
    private static ModelLoader modelLoader;
    private static Renderer renderer;
    private static long windowID;

    // Methods
    /**
     * Entry method of the engine.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayManager = DisplayManager.getInstance();
        displayManager.init(); // CONTEXT IS INITIALIZED
        windowID = displayManager.getWindowID();
        modelLoader = ModelLoader.getInstance();
        renderer = Renderer.getInstance();

        // Creating a square.
        float[] vertices = {
                // Left bottom triangle
                -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                // Right top triangle
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
                -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f
        };
        RawModel square = modelLoader.loadToVAO(vertices); // IT FAILS HERE
        List<RawModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(square);
        update(models);
    }

    /**
     * Update loop.
     */
    private static void update(List<RawModel> models) {
        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(windowID)) {
            renderer.prepare();
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glfwSwapBuffers(windowID);
            glfwPollEvents();
            models.forEach(model -> renderer.render(model));
        }
        modelLoader.cleanup();
        displayManager.destroy();
    }
}
```

ModelLoader.java:

```java
package engine;

import graphics.DisplayManager;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ModelLoader {

    // Attributes
    private static ModelLoader instance = new ModelLoader();
    private List<Integer> vaoList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer> vboList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructors
    private ModelLoader(){}

    // Methods
    public RawModel loadToVAO(float[] vertexPositions) {
        int vaoID = createVAO();
        storeDataInAttrList(vertexPositions, 0);
        unbindVAO();
        return new RawModel(vaoID, vertexPositions.length / 3);
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        vaoList.forEach(GL30::glDeleteVertexArrays);
        vboList.forEach(GL30::glDeleteBuffers);
    }

    /**
     * @return the ID of the VAO it creates.
     */
    private int createVAO() {
        int vaoID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        vaoList.add(vaoID);
        return vaoID;
    }

    private void unbindVAO(){
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    private int createVBO() {
        int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        vboList.add(vboID);
        return vboID;
    }

    private void storeDataInAttrList(float[] data, int attrPos) {
        int vboID = createVBO();
        FloatBuffer buffer = convertArrayToFloatBuffer(data);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(attrPos, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        // Unbinding VBO.
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }



    private FloatBuffer convertArrayToFloatBuffer(float[] data) {
        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }

    public static ModelLoader getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

DisplayManager.java:

```java
package graphics;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwShowWindow;
import static constants.DisplayConstants.*;

/**
 * @author Rafael Barbieru
 * Managing class of the display.
 */
public class DisplayManager {

    // Attributes
    private static DisplayManager instance = new DisplayManager();
    private GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback;
    private long windowID;

    // Constructors
    private DisplayManager(){}

    // Methods
    /**
     * Initializes the GLFW window.
     */
    public void init() {
        // In case something fails, GLFW prints the message to System.err.
        errorCallback = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err);
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);

        // Initializing GLFW
        boolean glfwInitSuccess = glfwInit();
        if (!glfwInitSuccess)
            throw new IllegalStateException("GLFW init failed!");

        // Creating the window.
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);
        windowID = glfwCreateWindow(
                WINDOW_WIDTH,
                WINDOW_HEIGHT,
                WINDOW_TITLE,
                MemoryUtil.NULL,
                MemoryUtil.NULL
        );
        if (windowID == MemoryUtil.NULL)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Window creation failed!");

        // Initializing the OGL context.
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowID);
        glfwSwapInterval(1);
        glfwShowWindow(windowID);
        GL.createCapabilities();
    }

    /**
     * Destroys the created GLFW window and terminates the context.
     */
    public void destroy() {
        glfwDestroyWindow(windowID);
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    public static DisplayManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public long getWindowID() {
        return windowID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you don't request a specific OpenGL version during initialization, which one do you get? Check with `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`. You need at least 3.0 for VAOs.

Comment: @BDL I get "2.1 INTEL-18.7.4". So I have to specify what OGL version I want to initialize then? That makes sense.